# How to print a table with data being displayed in column format in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

Following is my php code:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
<?php

for ($i=1;$i<=8;$i++)
{
echo "<td>";
echo "<b>Col-".$i."</b><br>";
for ($j=1;$j<=15;$j++)
{

echo "Row-".$j."<br>";
}
echo "</td>";
}

?>
</tr>
</table>
```

So this basically prints the data values of each row header below them, column-wise that is.I want to implement the same in a Laravel view, wherein data would be passed from the controller to the view.

I tried implementing the same using the below code:

View:

```
<form action='/display' method="post">
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width:100%;" border=1>
 {!! csrf_field() !!}
 <thead>
   <tr>
     @foreach($todo as $todo)
     <td>
       {{$todo->status}}
       @foreach($todo1 as $todo1)
       <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            {{$todo1->summary}} 
            </td>
        </tr>

       </table>
       @endforeach
     </td>
     @endforeach
   </tr>
 </thead>
 </table>
```

Controller:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Todo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

//use Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection;
class TodoController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
{

  $todo=DB::table('todos')->select('status')->groupBy('status')->get();
  //dd($todo);
  $todo1=DB::table('todos')->where('status','todo')->get();
  //dd($todo1);
  return view ('display',compact('todo1','todo'));
}
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
ErrorException

Trying to get property of non-object (View: lar4/resources/views/display.blade.php)
```

Any suggestions on what needs to be done here, I just want the format of the table like the one in the php code that I described at the start.

Comment: Additionally, I don't think there is any issue with the data being passed here, as I tried passing the data for the column header i.e. todo, and was able to print them in the view.

Comment: I don't know laravel, but is there a reason `$todo=DB::table('todos')->select('status')` has a `->select()`, but `$todo1=DB::table('todos')` does not? Based on your error message, I would assume it is because of `$todo1->summary`.

Comment: @Sean since I use the group by clause here, I need to use select statement on the column that I use in group by,  that's the only reason I have used it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Trying changing your view

    <form action='/display' method="post">
     <table style="table-layout: fixed; width:100%;" border=1>
     {!! csrf_field() !!}
      <thead>
      <tr>
      @foreach($todo as $todo_new)
      <td>
        {{$todo_new->status}}
        @foreach($todo1 as $todo1_new)
        <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
            {{$todo1_new->summary}} 
            </td>
         </tr>

        </table>
        @endforeach
      </td>
      @endforeach
    </tr>
   </thead>
   </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess retrieving them with the same names was the problem here.